# Dynamically create checkbox and store value in a record field

Tags: inputcheckboxes, checkbox, apexinputcheckbox

I am trying to dynamically create a checkbox component and then store its value in a record's field.  I have a standard checkbox component that works.  I can't figure out how to dynamically create the same component & store the value of the checkbox.  I think my problem is related to the onCheck call.  I have onCheck in the controller of the component that is creating the dynamic checklist.  I can't seem to get to onCheck.  I am not sure if my syntax is create for trying to call onCheck dynamically.  Do I need to dynamically create onCheck, etc.?

```
                $A.createComponent(
                "ui:inputCheckbox",
                { 
                    "change" : "{!c.onCheck}",
                    "value" : component.getReference("v.EventRSVP."+ fieldAPIName),
                    "aura:id": "findableAuraId",
                    "label": fieldLabel
                },
```

Here is the component and controller that I have that work - not being created dynamically.
**Component**

```
<aura:component implements="force:appHostable,flexipage:availableForAllPageTypes">
<aura:attribute name="myBool" type="Boolean" default="false"/>
<ui:inputCheckbox aura:id="checkbox" label="Select?"  change="{!c.onCheck}"/>
<p>Selected:</p>
<p><ui:outputText class="result" aura:id="checkResult" value="false" /></p>
<p>The following checkbox uses a component attribute to bind its value.</p>
<ui:outputCheckbox aura:id="output" value="{!v.myBool}"/>
```

**Controller**

```
({
onCheck: function(cmp, evt) {
    var checkCmp = cmp.find("checkbox");
    var resultCmp = cmp.find("checkResult");
    resultCmp.set("v.value", ""+checkCmp.get("v.value"));
    cmp.set("v.myBool", checkCmp.get("v.value"));
}
```

})

Answer (score 0):

I just figured out my problem.  I needed the line in the dynamically created component to call onCheck by using the following code instead of what I had:

```
                        "change" : component.getReference("{!c.onCheck}"),
```